# OpenGL: Drawing 3D curves with varying width

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d

I am trying to draw a curve in 3D in which the width may vary. I am doing something similar to what described in [this tutorial](http://www.merowing.info/2012/04/drawing-smooth-lines-with-cocos2d-ios-inspired-by-paper/).

Meaning, i create quads (and triangles) with the desired width instead of using OpenGL width. The problem is that the triangles are actually in 2D - they are drawn in a specific plane. The width will look different, of course, from different angles.

Am i tackling this problem in the correct way? Is there a good solution for my problem?

Comment: The link at the end of the first paragraph is broken.

Comment: So you want, what, 3D tubes like from [GLE](http://www.linas.org/gle/)?  Or just billboarded quads?

Comment: @genpfault I read about billboards. Do you think it will be a good solution for my problem?

Comment: the whole drawing will be affected by camera angle, going 3d from your example is a bit of work! you have normals on each point; rotate them several times with the segment as axis to get your shape

Comment: What do you mean that i should rotate several times?

Comment: @Eric Sapir: for now you have the normal for each point at angle 0 and 180°, to make a volume with the same inputs, you have more angles. for example, a cylinder with 6 segment, you'll have to rotate your normal 5 times by 360/6°. (the segment is the axe of rotation)

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough question that i have recently come across while developing a game myself.

They way i handled it instead of drawing a line i would draw boxes as segments of the line. You could potential make cylinders but if your using lighting you could cheat boxes to look like cylinders.

You could also cross two quads to make an X of sorts along the length of the string.

Comment: I also thought of drawing cylinders or boxes. However, boxes will look wired if i am not looking in a 90 degrees angle. I thing a cylinder will also look a bit weird and not very natual

Comment: Is your "cord" textured or just colored?

Comment: Just colored triangles

Comment: Then it should be hard to tell the difference of width in a quad, to make the effect even better with lighting you can blend your normals to get a smooth cylinder like effect.

Comment: What do you mean that it would be hard to tell the difference of width in a quad?

Comment: Viewing from 90 degrees wont look much different then viewing from 45.

Comment: why is that? I will see the edges, no?

Comment: There are tricks around that, if you are lighting your scene blend your normals if your not lighting then you wont see the line or the separation.

Comment: What is the algorithm to turn lines into cylinders?

Comment: Take a cylinder mesh. Scale it along the symmetry axis to the legnth of the segment and scale the other axis by the radius.

Comment: I could not get what i want with such meshes - i need the curve to have varying width. It means that every part of the curve can have its own width. Of course all curve parts must be connected smoothly